# how to sort a column in a table in r

Tags: r, sorting, merge

I tried to merge two tables, but the result is like this,

```
 subj gamble_gamble n_gambles expected_value
   1            19        32            1.7
  10             3         4            1.5
 100             3         4            1.5
 101             6        32            1.4
 102             3         4            1.5
 103            19        32            1.7
```

The `subj` column isn't ordered in usual way (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6). I tried to order the `subj` column with this command:

```
newdata <- table3[order(subj),]
```

but it doesnt work. Can somebody help me?

Comment: That looks sorted to me.... What am I missing?

Comment: Probably `subj` is a character and you want it sorted like a numeric?

Comment: its not the full table, thats the few first table, the subj colum sort in 1,10,100,101... but I want it to be sorted in 1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Have you tried `table3[order(as.numeric(as.character(table3$subj))),]`?

Comment: @roland, I didn't see your comment. Post it as an answer and I'll delete mine :-)

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft Nah, you need the rep more than I do.

Comment: @elvita, the fact that you think the `subj` column should be sorted numerically, but it sorts by assuming `character` type, in case you dint deliberately convert to `character`, tells that your data may have other than numbers in that column. Worth checking before applying Roland's solution. As a check, when applying Roland's answer, if you get warnings, then it's an indication that something is not as expected.

Comment: @elvita, Two questions asked within a 24 hour period, both answered to a degree where you report in some manner that "it works". Do *consider* accepting such answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
newdata <- table3[order(as.numeric(as.character(table3$subj))),]
```

This works even if `subj` is a `factor` (not just `character`).